# asp.net jquery newbie question

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a webform that contains a file upload button.

when I click on the button to upload the file, the C# code behind contains some code in the event handler that I want to execute *first* before jquery executes.

```
<script>
    $(document.ready() {
        $('.uploadButton').click(function() {
            // do some additional processing *AFTER* code behind stuff executes
        });
    }
</script>

// In my ASP.NET C# code behind
protected void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code to fire off here *FIRST* before jquery executes
}
```

Is something like this possible?  I know I can implement a jquery post in my javascript, but since I have most of the code already laid out (and am changing this on a client request), I was just wondering if something like this was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not possible**

The `OnClick` and jQuery event handlers are executed first and only after that the page is posted back and you're able to run the code in in your server.

The best thing that you can do is to use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

here's some code to help you.

In your code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string uploadButton_Click(string name)
{
   return "Good bye World! by" + name ;
}
```

And in js file

```
$(".uploadButton").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "PageName.aspx/uploadButton_Click",
      data: "{'Name':'Mr.X'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
          alert(msg.d) // will show up an alert box with Good bye world by Mr.X
      }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the jQuery click handler. Wrap your code in a function and assign that function name to the OnClientClick property of the button. You can return false to prevent the post-back from processing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the best option to choose. If you dont wannna use AJAX, then probably u can do this(perhaps the dirty-logic)

Do nothing with jQuery before the server is hit. In your code-behind

```
// In my ASP.NET C# code behind
protected void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code to fire off here *FIRST* before jquery executes

    string strClientQuery = @"<script type="javascript"> $(document.ready() {
        $('.uploadButton').click(function() {
        // do some additional processing *AFTER* code behind stuff executes
        });
       }  </script>";
    Response.Write(strClientQuery);
}
```

If you want to keep the script strictly in client-side(i.e aspx page), then create the query as string in the aspx and pass it as an input to the page(through _EventTarget and in code-behind get the string and do response.write
 **If you find the answser is useful, please take a few seconds to rate it**